# Storing JSON in an msSQL database?

Tags: json, sql, forms

I'm developing a form generator, and wondering if it would be bad mojo to store JSON in an SQL database?

I want to keep my database & tables simple, so I was going to have

```
`pKey, formTitle, formJSON`
```

on a table, and then store

```
{["firstName":{"required":"true","type":"text"},"lastName":{"required":"true","type":"text"}}
```

in formJSON.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use JSON extensively in my CMS (which hosts about 110 sites) and I find the speed of access data to be very fast.  I was surprised that there wasn't more speed degradation.  Every object in the CMS (Page, Layout, List, Topic, etc) has an NVARCHAR(MAX) column called JSONConfiguration.  My ORM tool knows to look for that column and reconstitute it as an object if needed.  Or, depending on the situation, I will just pass it to the client for jQuery or Ext JS to process.

As for readability / maintainability of my code, you might say it's improved because I now have classes that represent a lot of the JSON objects stored in the DB.

I used JSON.net for all serialization / deserialization. [https://www.newtonsoft.com/json](http://james.newtonking.com/default.aspx)

I also use a single query to return meta-JSON with the actual data.  As in the case of Ext JS, I have queries that return both the structure of the Ext JS object as well as the data the object will need.  This cuts out one post back / SQL round trip.

I was also surprised at how fast the code was to parse a list of JSON objects and map them into a DataTable object that I then handed to a GridView.

The only downside I've seen to using JSON is indexing.  If you have a property of the JSON you need to search, then you have to store it as a separate column.

There are JSON DB's out there that might server your needs better:  CouchDB, MongoDB, and Cassandra.

Answer (score 7):

A brilliant way to make an object database from sql server. I do this for all config objects and everything else that doesn't need any specific querying. extending your object - easy, just create a new property in your class and init with default value. Don't need a property any more? Just delete it in the class. Easy roll out, easy upgrade. Not suitable for all objects, but if you extract any prop you need to index on - keep using it. Very modern way of using sql server.

Comment: I've run into many occasions where I'm hunting for a solution and find my way here. In the hunt for the solution, I sometimes find a better answer elsewhere and maybe with newer technology than which what was answered at the time. It's not only to answer YOUR question, but for everyone who runs into the same situation as you in the future. And like KOPEHb, I'll be courteous enough to update or even provide better solutions than was answered.

Answer (score 3):

It will be slower than having the form defined in code, but one extra query shouldn't cause you much harm. (Just don't let 1 extra query become 10 extra queries!)

Edit: If you are selecting the row by `formTitle` instead of `pKey` (I would, because then your code will be more readable), put an index on `formTitle`

Answer (score 3):

We have used a modified version of XML for exactly the purpose you decribe for seven or eight years and it works great. Our customers' form needs are so diverse that we could never keep up with a table/column approach.  We are too far down the XML road to change very easily but I think JSON would work as well and maybe evan better.

Reporting is no problem with a couple of good parsing functions and I would defy anyone to find a significant difference in performance between our reporting/analytics and a table/column solution to this need.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it.

If you ever want to do any reporting or query based on these values in the future it's going to make your life a lot harder than having a few extra tables/columns.

Why are you avoiding making new tables?  I say if your application requires them go ahead and add them in...  Also if someone has to go through your code/db later it's probably going to be harder for them to figure out what you had going on (depending on what kind of documentation you have).

Comment: We spend a lot of time on custom forms, that generally contain the same information, most of that information gets stored into only 3-4 different tables. SO if I could create the forms programmatically, and submit them into their appropriate tables it would save a lot of development time in the future.

Comment: I think in that situation it's probably going to be fine.  Like Michael says it will just be one extra query.  I thought you were trying to store values along with the structure of the form.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use SisoDb for this. http://sisodb.com

Comment: Does anyone have any opinions after using SisoDB?  It looks promising, but this kind of library can really be hit or miss when used in practice...

Comment: Hi, I'm biased since I build SisoDB but we are using it in a commercial product being developed today. It's used for maintaining readmodels in a CQRS environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think it not an optimal idea to store object data in a string in SQL.  You have to do transformation outside of SQL in order to parse it.  That presents a performance issue and you lose the leverage of using SQL native data parsing capability.  A better way would be to store  JSON as an XML datatype in SQL.  This way, you kill two birds with one stone: You don't have to create shit load of tables and still get all the native querying benefits of SQL.

[XML in SQL Server 2005? Better than JSON in Varchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821782/xml-in-sql-server-2005-better-than-json-in-varchar)