# XML in SQL Server 2005? Better than JSON in Varchar?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, json

What are the benefits of storing XML in SQL Server over storing JSON in a varchar field?

Any tutorial available for how to use the XML data type effectively?

Do I need to provide the dtd / xml schema somehow?  I've heard it is optional, right?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: here's the answer to the last part of the Q.

> XML schema information is used in
>   storage and query optimizations. Typed
>   XML instances contain typed values in
>   the internal, binary representation as
>   well as in XML indexes. This provides
>   efficient processing of typed XML
>   data.

quoted from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML in SQL Server 2005 and up allows you to directly manipulate the XML stored inside the database table using XQuery - you can't really do that with JSON in a VARCHAR field.

Check out [XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [Fundamentals of the XML Datatype in SQL Server 2005](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3531196/The-Fundamentals-of-the-SQL-Server-2005-XML-Datatype.htm) for more info and more background.

Also, the XML stored in a XML column in SQL Server is "tokenized" and pre-parsed - it's not just stored as plain text. And you can even put indices on your XML - on its nodes, its values - whatever you need.

Answer (score 5):

Storing it as XML allows you to leverage the SQL XML support: XPATH, XQUERY, XML Indexes and such. These allow for efficient search and manipulation of the content. I recommend you read [XML Best Practices for Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345115%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

JSON content in VARCHAR would be opaque to searches and manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

1. XML can be indexed for more performant querying.
2. Data can be extracted from XML data usng XPath.
3. A schema can be provided to constrain the XML to a secifiation but this is optional.
4. Client libraries understan the XML data type and can send/receive it more carefully/easily.

None of the above is available for JSON stored in varchar.

Answer (score 1):

you can query for individual xml property values if you use the xml data type. I don't believe the same functionality is available for json:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx

I don't believe that the xsd is required as I've used the query feature without having that defined before

Comment: Honestly, I don't know ... the feature I implemented it may as well have used json as it was just used as a blob storage. Though I did find it useful to troubleshoot some issues a few times that I could query within that field. So I've never had a production feature use this

Comment: @Henry: You can add xml indexes to help if necessary: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Henry, the XML data type will be more efficient and optimized than parsing the same data in a plain varchar column!!!

Answer (score 1):

Storing XML in SQL 2005 is great. You can put the whole XML file in a single field, then run SELECT commands to pull out certain attributes and elements. Putting a XSD is not neccesary. I don't believe it has any JSON support even in 2008 although I could be wrong. [Here's a good starter article](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050803.htm) on it.