# Store data in JSON instead of mySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I know JSON is more for data transit/interchange, but can I store a simple mySQL database in JSON on server-side? And how do you do it?

Thanks,

Jane

Edit: I didn't mean store a database in JSON, just put some values into it.

Comment: And by serverside you mean in the filesystem?

Comment: Any way on server-side that can be read and sent to clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store a SQL database *inside* JSON - JSON is a data format. You could pull values from your SQL database and convert to JSON for interchange with client.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, just store corresponding values. Do you know how to save the JSON data on server?

Comment: @Jane Depends what server side language you're working with and where you're getting the JSON data from. Check out http://json.org/ for info on JSON api's for different languages - once you understand how to use JSON in your language, you can easily push it into your

Comment: I'm using server-side javascript, and now I just store some values in a json variable, like "var a = {}". I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it. It seems easiy to be lost once the server got problems.

Comment: @Jane If you've got your JSON values stored in a variables, of course that won't work. It only stays for as long as that code executes. You have to store it somewhere. If you've already got your data in JSON format, great. just pull it out and stick it in a database. But that's your job, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org), which is a database system with a core functionality of storing JSON documents.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out: [Storing JSON in an msSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497678/storing-json-in-an-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the JSON feed in the database. you should be able to persist the JSON feed in the database as a column type char/varchar2