# Insert JSON file into SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Hi how can I insert a `JSON` file into a Cell in `Database`? I don't want to store the File path but want to store the whole `Content` of the `JSON` file into the field.

What can I do?

Comment: search if there are similar questions before you post. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497678/storing-json-in-an-mssql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON data stored/transferred in as a string. You can store it in a normal NVARCHAR column.

Comment: But there seems to be a length limit for the NVARCHAR? It's 4000 as said here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx. What if my JSON text file has more than 4000 characters?

Comment: @ethanjyx the max size for NVARCHAR(MAX) is 2 GB

Answer (score 0):

how large is the json text?, depending on that you should have a varchar field if content is not large or CLOB if is a lot of json text, 
json is just text , so you just have something to read the content of the file, maybe some transact-sql script , and insert it in your table

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can store the json file in a NVARCHAR(MAX) column. Here is an example how to load a json file into a NVARCHAR(MAX) variable.

Consider this sample .json file *top-posts.json*:

```
[
   {
      "Id":6107,
      "Score":176,
      "ViewCount":155988,
      "Title":"What are deconvolutional layers?",
      "OwnerUserId":8820
   },
   {
      "Id":155,
      "Score":164,
      "ViewCount":25822,
      "Title":"Publicly Available Datasets",
      "OwnerUserId":227
   }
]
```

Here is a SQL script to import the json file using *OPENROWSET* and Bulk import. We also pass in the path to the folder where the json file is. It is put in the same folder as the .sql file script.

Sql-script *import_json_file_openrowset.sql*:

```
DECLARE @JSONFILE VARCHAR(MAX); 

SELECT @JSONFILE = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '$(FullScriptDir)\top-posts.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j;

PRINT 'JsonFile contents: ' + @JSONFILE

IF (ISJSON(@JSONFILE)=1) PRINT 'It is valid Json';
```

The .bat file here passes the current folder as a variable to the sql script

*runsqlscript.bat*

```
@set FullScriptDir=%CD%
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS  -i import_json_file_openrowset.sql
```

This outputs:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS  -i import_json_file_openrowset.sql
JsonFile contents: [
   {
      "Id":6107,
      "Score":176,
      "ViewCount":155988,
      "Title":"Toreboss: What are deconvolutional layers?",
      "OwnerUserId":8820
   },
   {
      "Id":155,
      "Score":164,
      "ViewCount":25822,
      "Title":"Publicly Available Datasets",
      "OwnerUserId":227
   }
]
It is valid Json
```

With the variable *JSONFILE* you can do whatever with it such as inserting it to a column in a new row of a table for example.